# what does it mean when the text "Asset" is getting displayed on your RoR website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried to implement a commenting system on my Ruby on Rails website. 
I basically followed these guidelines from this thread: [Micropost's comments on users page (Ruby on Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669221/microposts-comments-on-users-page-ruby-on-rails)

However, the comment doesn't show when I post and the text "Asset" is displayed on top of every comment box. Where is this coming from?

Updated with codes:
I am using three models to try to get the comments working as shown in the above link

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments
```

micropost.rb

```
 class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :image, :comment_content
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true

  default_scope order: 'microposts.created_at DESC'

  def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
    followed_user_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                         WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
    where("user_id IN (#{followed_user_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id", 
          user_id: user.id)
  end
end
```

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comment_content

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :micropost

  validates :comment_content, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :micropost_id, presence: true  
end
```

comments controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
     def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.micropost = @micropost
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
       redirect_to(:back)
    else
      render 'shared/_comment_form'
    end
  end
end
```

micropost controller

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user
  before_filter :correct_user, only: :destroy

    def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Posted"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by_id(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_path if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

user controller

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @comment = Comment.new
  end
```

comment form

```
<%= form_for([micropost, @comment]) do |f| %>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :microposts do
  resources :comments
end
```

micropost view

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= simple_format(micropost.content) %></span>
  <%= image_tag micropost.image_url(:thumb).to_s %><br>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
 <%= render 'shared/comment_form', micropost: micropost %>
 <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", micropost, method: :delete,
                                     confirm: "You sure?",
                                     title: micropost.content %><br>

  <% end %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have some static informations in one of your partials or in the form control that render your textarea for the comment?

Check you view for the controller or maybe it is somewhere in the `'static_pages/home'`

EDIT: 
Just full search your project for the text asset, maybe you find an image alt="assets" tag for an image and the image is not available.

Comment: do you think it's something with the images? I posted the micropost view which is the most important one

Comment: If I dunderstand you correct you say that you have a text "asset" in your form. So it is rendered somewhere. Check you `shared/comment_form`, maybe there is a placeholder text. OR: It is an alt tag of an image and the image is not available so the alt text is rendered.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was asking. However, there is no place where I even used the text "Asset" anywhere. The text can't even be highlighted with my mouse cursor on the page where it's shown

Comment: Check your rendered html code. Then check what html tag render your asset text, afterwards check your views for this tag and remove/edit it.

Comment: Is `micropost.image_url(:thumb).to_s` a valid image and exists?