# Displaying microposts' comments for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Building upon [Micropost's comments on users page (Ruby on Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669221/microposts-comments-on-users-page-ruby-on-rails) , I was able to add new comments for each micropost. However, I'm having problem displaying back the comments for each post on the same page. The codes below didn't throw any error, so I'm thinking the each micropost's comments are not assigned correctly so it can't display.

*Users* > *Microposts* > *Comments*

**users_controller.rb**

```
  def show
    @user = Account.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts
    @micropost = Micropost.new
    @comments = @micropost.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
  end
```

**microposts/_micropost.html.erb**

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>

  <span class="comments">
    <% if micropost.comments.any? %>
    <ul class="comments">
      <%= render @comments%>
    </ul>
    <% end %>

    <%= render "shared/form_comment", micropost: micropost %>
  </span>

</li>
```

**comments/_comment.html.erb**

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= comment.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `<%= render @comments%>` to `<%= render micropost.comments %>` to loop through the specific post's comments instead of using generic comment loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>

  <span class="comments">
    <ul class="comments">
      <%= render micropost.comments %> # you can leave out the #any?
    </ul>
   </span>

</li>
```

Comment: got error **stack level too deep** when i made the above changes. also, the render is for the comment form for the post